# Kubuntu Boot Up Speed

Tags: boot

It's been suggested I move to Kubuntu, GCC, and open GL for these small but critical applications.

But Kubuntu 11.0 takes over 10 minutes to boot with a CF card for a drive and an AMD GX466 CPU.

The application I am attempting to port over to Kubuntu from DOS takes about 20 seconds to boot.

Seriously, is that standard for Kubuntu? I read that Linux is not a good choice for mission critical embedded applications. Perhaps this is why and why DOS continues to be used in these critical apps.

Is there some way to get Kubuntu to boot in 20 seconds. We only need SVGA, network packet driver, and a USB mouse to be loaded as drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar). In your case I would even go for something more light-weighted that isn't based on Ubuntu at all.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of boot depends on two things: hardware and software.

The more the software does (GUI, animations, background tasks, user management, shell execution, etc) the slower your computer. Kubuntu does a lot more than DOS. If DOS is working for you and does everything you need.

If you need new features, Lubuntu may boot faster than Kubuntu. It's lighter and does less.

Now the hardware. I have a top of the range PC with 32GB RAM, 6 x Intel i7 at 3200 MHz cores and a 2TB HDD at 90MB/s.

You have an old computer with a small amount of RAM, a 333 MHz processor (an order of magnitude slower). You also have a CF card with 30 MB/s read / write.

You wouldn't expect this guy to lift these weights.

[image] [image]

Equally, you can't expect this computer to do all this.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Kubuntu is the version of Ubuntu that runs the K Desktop Environment, a fully-featured desktop OS, and is one of the "chunkier" flavors of Ubuntu. Once installed, it tends to run a bit faster than when booted off of a "Live" image, but it will still be slow on your (very limited) hardware.

If you *need* an up-to-date (but lightweight) graphical environment, I would second Tim's suggestion of using Lubuntu instead, but on your hardware even Lubuntu would not be fast.

However, if you are comfortable on the Linux command line and do not need a graphical user interface (GUI), take a look at Ubuntu Server -- it will allow you to install a command-line-only system (not necessarily a server), without a GUI. This would probably run reasonably on your hardware.

Comment: Add to that that the command-line-only configuration is just the default of Ubuntu Server. You can always install graphical tools and desktop environments later.